# Ionic back button showing also in the previous page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm using the following code to show a back button in a nested page ('menu.settings.term_of_service'):

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button icon ion-chevron-left"  ui-sref="menu.settings" ></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

here is also the routes.js:

```
.state('menu.settings.term_of_service', {
        url: '/term_of_service',
          views: {
          'side-menu-ineevent@menu' :{
            templateUrl:'templates/term_of_service.html'
          }
        }
    })

    .state('menu.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        cache: false,
        views: {
          'side-menu-ineevent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
          }
        }
    })
```

the problem is that when I press it, in the page ('menu.settings') it still shows the back button to come back again in the 'menu.settings.term_of_service' page instead of the 'menu' bar. Any idea?

Comment: Can you clarify; So you have the problem where the back button takes you from 'menu.settings' to 'menu.settings.terms_of_serivce' instead of 'menu'?

Comment: the way around: when you are in 'menu.settings' from the 'menu.settings.terms_of_serivce'  (thourgh backbutton): the 'menu.settings' page in this case still show another backbutton to come back again in the 'menu.settings.terms_of_serivce' .

Comment: Did you try changin `'side-menu-ineevent@menu` to `'side-menu-ineevent` ? The routing uses a stack history per view.